# nativescript angular how to load more data

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

i want to load the data from api while scroll down . First time am displaying 15 data's after scroll down i want to show another 15 data.

this is my typescript code

```
this._search.application(p).then(
      data => {
        this.items = data["response"]["docs"];
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Subscription error:", error);
      }
    );
```

}

this is my html code

```
 <ListView *ngIf="dataRender" [items]="items"   separatorColor="transparent">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                <StackLayout class="main" style="border:3px solid red">
                    <StackLayout class="content" style="border:3px solid red">
                        <Image (tap)="gtoview(item.id)" stretch="aspectFill" class="card-img" [src]="imagePath(item)">
                        </Image>
                        <GridLayout width="100%" columns="auto" rows="auto,auto,auto" class="" verticalAlignment="center">

                            <Label row="0"  col="1" class="item-name" textwrap="true" verticalAlignment="bottom"
                                horizontalAlignment="left" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                              <Label row="1"  col="1"  [text]="getAddress(item)"></Label> 

                           <Label row="2"  col="1" [text]="getPhone(item)"> </Label>

                        </GridLayout>
                        <StackLayout width="100%" marginTop="5" class="line"></StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout width="100%" class="lineBreak"></StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
```

Let me know how to use ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [loadMoreItems](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview#loadmoreitemsevent) event which is raised when the last item on your ListView is visible, you may hit the API and add more items to your array in the event callback.